# Why TWTweetComposeViewController does not show accounts selector?

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter

I want to add tweet sending capability from my app. I use `TWTweetComposeViewController` creating the controller and showing it modally.

The device, or simulator, **has several accounts set up**, but compose controller does not show the accounts selector.

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? Is this a problem of landscape orientation?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested it on my device, it appears that the account drop-down menu/selection isn't available when the orientation is landscape.